# Pegar string entre barras de uma variável PHP

Tags: php

Como pegar a string que esta dentro das duas primeiras barras (naacoclqtsafkbsk) com PHP?

recebo a url pelo GET

`$url = $_GET['url']`

```
// https://streamango.com/embed/naacoclqtsafkbsk/L3j3md0fD3N4g4P34rIz_Legendado_mp4
```

Comment: ela sempre vai ser a quarta?

Comment: Talvez pode mudar por causa de diferentes nomes de arquivos... o tamanho pode afetar eu acho

Answer (score 1):

O valor que você deseja é o que chamamos de segmento de caminho da URL (do inglês, *segment path*). Para isso, o ideal é tratar a URL como uma URL através da função `parse_url`:

```
$url = parse_url('https://streamango.com/embed/naacoclqtsafkbsk/L3j3md0fD3N4g4P34rIz_Legendado_mp4');
```

Assim, pegamos apenas a parte do *path* da URL:

```
$path = trim($url['path'] ?? '/', '/');
```

Com o operador `??` garantimos que se a URL não possuir um *path* seja considerado a string `"/"`, tal como recomenda a RFC. Com a função `trim` removemos qualquer barra do início ou fim do *path*, pois para nós, neste ponto, não serão úteis.

Para a string dada na questão, o valor de `$path` será:

```
embed/naacoclqtsafkbsk/L3j3md0fD3N4g4P34rIz_Legendado_mp4
```

Assim, dividimos a string nas barras, gerando um array com todos os segmentos de caminho da URL:

```
$segments = explode('/', $path);
```

Que será o array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => embed
    [1] => naacoclqtsafkbsk
    [2] => L3j3md0fD3N4g4P34rIz_Legendado_mp4
)
```

Com isso, basta você definir qual posição do array lhe é interessante, visto que pelo [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351479/pegar-string-entre-barras-de-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-php#comment705358_351479) isso não parece estar muito definido ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada na função  [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) - Interpreta uma URL e retorna os seus componentes.

A parte em que você está interessado é o caminho, então você pode passar o `PHP_URL_PATH` como o segundo argumento.

```
$url = "https://streamango.com/embed/naacoclqtsafkbsk/L3j3md0fD3N4g4P34rIz_Legendado_mp4";

//var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
//string(58) "/embed/naacoclqtsafkbsk/L3j3md0fD3N4g4P34rIz_Legendado_mp4"

$uriSegmentos = explode("/", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));

echo $uriSegmentos[2];
```

[**ideone**](https://ideone.com/x5amy7)